# ngc: Error: Unexpected value 'ChartsModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

When compiling my ionic2 app for android, I get this error:

`ngc: Error: Unexpected value 'ChartsModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'`

If I only build it using `ionic serve` (bypassing angular2 AOT) then it builds and runs fine.

I believe this error is due to **the lack of metatdata.json file** in the Telerik charts bundle (I only use the charts but I guess there's the same issue for other components).

Other vendors have the same problem, see ticket here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262

Could this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of writing, AOT compilation is not supported in the Kendo UI for Angular 2 components. We are making progress on making it available across components, as [stated on the roadmap page](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/).

**Update (Dec 2016)**: AoT compilation is now enabled and supported for all Kendo UI for Angular 2 components. See the [AoT compilation help topic](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/aot/) for more information.

Comment: You can track our progress in https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/49

Comment: Thanks for the update. However the roadmap mentions January 2017. Any chance we can get this one earlier? I'm building a POC charts application, which must be ready before December this year. Not having AOT-compliant plugins make them pretty much useless anyway.

Comment: Features are published on npm as they become available. The task is already in progress, so it is quite likely to ship before the roadmap deadline. However, we cannot guarantee a release date.

Comment: This is no longer true, all packages support AoT and Tree Shaking. See http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/aot/